# Topology - continuous functions

Tags: general-topology

I am answering the question:

Let $X = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ with topology $\{\emptyset, X, \{1\}, \{3, 4\}, \{1, 3, 4\}\}$, and let $Y = \{A, B\}$ with topology $\{\emptyset, Y, \{A\}\}$. Find all continuous functions from $X$ to $Y$. How many functions from $X$ to $Y$ are there altogether?

This is what I have thus far:

Let $(X,\tau)$ and $(Y,\tau^\prime)$ be topological spaces. A function from $X$ to $Y$ is said to be **continuous** if given any open subset $U$ of $Y$, then $f^{-1}(U)$ is an open subset of $X$.

**a.**
Continuous functions from $X$ to $Y$ can be characterized as those that map open subsets of $X$ to open subsets to $Y$. In total, there exist $8$ continuous functions from $X$ to $Y$:
\begin{align*}
f&: \{{1}\} \rightarrow A\\
f&: \{{3, 4}\} \rightarrow A \\
f&: \{{1, 3, 4}\} \rightarrow A \\
f&: X \rightarrow A \\
f&: \{{1}\} \rightarrow Y \\
f&: \{{3, 4}\} \rightarrow Y \\
f&: \{{1, 3, 4}\} \rightarrow Y \\
f&: X \rightarrow Y
\end{align*}

My question is: how do I handle the empty set? I know that if I am mapping to or from the empty set, $X \times Y = \emptyset$, i.e. $\emptyset$ is the only subset of $X \times Y$. So, we shouldn't be able to map $\emptyset$ to a nonempty set, correct? And, should we be able to map a nonempty set to $\emptyset$? Thanks for the help y'all!

Comment: These $f^i$ are not even functions

Comment: No, we shouldn't be able to "map $\emptyset$ to a nonempty set", neither should we be able to "map a nonempty set to $\emptyset$." But I think the way you're looking at this is slightly off: in the first instance all we want are functions $f$ from $X$ to $Y$, i.e. all you need to do is say what $1,2,3,4,5 \in X$ each map to. Then all you need to do is check if the set of things in $X$ that map to $A \in Y$ (**note:** $A\in Y$, **not** $\{A\} \subset Y$) is open. In your list of continuous functions $f^i$, you're doing something funky with the sets, and that's the off bit.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by $X\times Y = \emptyset$?

Comment: I believe that describes what I did--does it not? Yes, I know that I labeled my functions strangely. I wanted to number them, but should not have done it that way in retrospect.

Comment: I mean that the function X to Y is a subset of X x Y, satisfying certain conditions. Is this not how one usually says that?

Answer (score 5):

The fact that the preimage of an open is open IS NOT equivalent to the fact that $f$ maps open sets to open sets. Such maps are called *open maps*. There exist continuous maps that are not open, open maps that are not continuous, open continuous maps and maps which are neither continuous nor open!

To find continuous maps from $X$ to $Y$ in your case amounts exactly to find all the possible preimages of $A$. Since $Y$ has only two elements, the preimage of $A$ determines uniquely the map. So there are exactly 5 continuous maps $X\to Y$. Two of them are the constant ones, the third is the one mapping $1$ to $A$ (and everything else to $B$), the fourth is the one mapping $3$ and $4$ to $A$ and the fifth maps $1$,$3$ and $4$ to $A$.

You don't have to care about $\varnothing$, because its preimage under any map is again $\varnothing$ which has to be open by definition of topology. In the same way, you don't have to care about the preimage of $Y$, which is always $X$.

Comment: What are the two "constant ones?" If I am disregarding any mapping of the empty set or of X to Y, what is left over that you are denoting as the two constant ones? Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: One is the map sending everything to $A$, the other one is the map sending everything to $B$.

Comment: But mapping everything to B would not be a constant function since B is not an open set, correct?

Comment: constant map=mapping everything to a point. Mapping everything to $B$ is continuous, since the preimage of $A$ is the empty set which is open.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**: First, let me clarify some notation and definitions that I will be using here. Suppose we have a set $X$ and a set $Y.$ Then we say that a subset $f$ of $X\times Y$ is a function from $X$ into $Y$--denoted $f:X\to Y$--if and only if for each $x\in X$ there is a unique $y\in Y$ such that $\langle x,y\rangle\in f$--and we call this unique $y$ by the name $f(x).$ Given $S\subseteq Y,$ the preimage of $S$ under $f$ will be denoted and defined by $$f^{-1}[S]:=\{x\in X:f(y)\in S\}.$$

If $X$ and $Y$ have been given topologies--say $\mathcal T_X$ and $\mathcal T_Y$, respectively--then we say that $f:X\to Y$ is continuous if and only if for each $U\in\mathcal T_Y$ we have $f^{-1}[U]\in\mathcal T_X.$ A few nice facts about preimages that will help for this problem (I leave them to you to verify, by definition of preimage and function):

> Given any sets $X,Y$ and any function $f:X\to Y,$ we have $f^{-1}[\emptyset]=\emptyset$ and $f^{-1}[Y]=X.$

As a consequence of these facts, a function $f:X\to Y$ (where $X$ and $Y$ have been given topologies) will be continuous if and only if each *non-trivial* open subset of $Y$ has an open preimage under $f.$ For this particular example, this means that $f:X\to Y$ is continuous if and only if $$f^{-1}\bigl[\{A\}\bigr]\in\bigl\{\emptyset,X,\{1\},\{3,4\},\{1,3,4\}\bigr\}.$$

Now, as a rule, if we have some sets $X$ and $Y$ and some $f:X\to Y,$ and if $S$ is a proper subset of $Y,$ then knowing what $f^{-1}[S]$ is won't be enough to tell us how $f$ is defined. In fact, it will be enough if and only if $Y$ has at most two elements, and exactly one element more than $S.$ (Why? It's a nice exercise to prove this result.) Fortunately, in your particular example, $Y$ has exactly two elements, and exactly one element more than $\{A\}\subsetneq Y.$ So, determining the preimage of $\{A\}$ under $f$ is *identical* to determining $f.$

For instance, in order to have $f:X\to Y$ such that $f^{-1}\bigl[\{A\}\bigr]=\{1,3,4\},$ we must have $$f(x):=\begin{cases}A & \text{if }x=1,3,\text{ or }4\\B & \text{if }x=2\text{ or }5.\end{cases}$$ It should be clear that this function gives us the desired preimage, but why can't any *other* function $X\to Y$ give us the same preimage? Well, note that if $g:X\to Y,$ then $$g^{-1}\bigl[\{A\}\bigr]:=\bigl\{x\in X:g(x)\in\{A\}\bigr\}=\{x\in X:g(x)=A\}.$$ Thus, in order to have $g^{-1}\bigl[\{A\}\bigr]=\{1,3,4\},$ we need to know that $g(x)=A$ if and only if $x\in\{1,3,4\}.$ Knowing that $g(x)=A$ for all $x\in\{1,3,4\}$ determines $g(x)$ for most of our $x\in X,$ and knowing that $B$ is the only element of $Y$ that *isn't* equal to $A$ tells us that $g(x)=B$ for all $x\in X\setminus\{1,3,4\}=\{2,5\}.$ Hence, $g(x)=f(x)$ (where $f$ is as defined above) for all $x\in X.$

The other $4$ continuous functions $f:X\to Y$ are as follows:

$$f(x):=\begin{cases}A & \text{if }x=3\text{ or }4\\B & \text{if }x=1,2\text{ or }5\end{cases}$$

$$f(x):=\begin{cases}A & \text{if }x=1\\B & \text{if }x=2,3,4,\text{ or }5\end{cases}$$

$$f(x):=A\: (\text{for all }x\in X)$$

$$f(x):=B\: (\text{for all }x\in X)$$

I leave it to you to verify that $f^{-1}\bigl[\{A\}\bigr]$ is indeed open in each case.

Comment: Actually there are five, corresponding to the five open subsets of $X$.

Comment: @Stefan: D'oh! Thank you. Fixed.

Comment: Could you specify why the 8 functions that I have listed are not the complete list of continuous functions from X to Y? I adopted the strategy of mapping each open set 9

Comment: Would you be able to specify why my list of 8 functions is not the exhaustive list of continuous functions from X to Y? I adopted the approach of mapping each open set in X to each open set in Y (as denoted by the defined topologies).

Comment: Your notation is highly ambiguous. In the first $4$ lines, you appear to be mapping a set into an element of $Y$ (which is nonsensical, but I suppose you mean that the elements of that set are those that are being mapped to $A$). If I take that interpretation on your last $4,$ though, you *haven't* defined the function!* For example, in the function $f$ on your fifth line, what is $f(1)$? It cannot be $Y$, since $Y$ is *not an element* of $Y$.

Comment: The functions are arbitrary, and need only to map sets of X to sets of Y. In the first four lines, I am mapping subsets of X, to a subset of Y.

Comment: @SKA: The functions you are finding should  **not** be arbitrary, and they need to map **elements** of $X$ to **elements** of $Y.$ Moreover, $A$ is **not** *a priori* a subset of $Y,$ so you are **not** doing what you claim in your first four lines.

Comment: Finally, notation exists for a reason: to communicate ideas in briefer form. Using it sloppily or inconsistently is like talking in gibberish. (For example, we want to talk about how many continuous functions $f:X\to Y$ there are, so how does "$f:X\to Y$" specify a *particular* function of this sort?) Be careful with your notation. I will expand my answer when I have some more time to do so.

Comment: Hmm.. There must be some sort of poor communication going on here then. I showed my work to a professor, and he said that I was answering the problem correctly. But, I don't know how to correct the misunderstanding that we are experiencing.

Comment: @SKA: I am on my way home now. Once I get there and have access to a keyboard (rather than thumb-typing on my phone), I will update my answer with a more thorough explanation. I hope to have it posted within about $90$ minutes.

Comment: Haha fair enough. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @SKA: My updated answer is now posted. Take a look and see if it clears anything up for you. Feel free to ask for further clarification if you need it. (I'm glad to help.)

Comment: @CameronBuie It seems simple to verify that due to $A$ being open, its preimage is open. After all, they're in the topologies, but how would I show that $B$ is open? Does that stem from the fact that $Y$ is clopen because a topology is defined on it, so we know that the subset of $Y$ is also clopen, hence $B$ is clopen, which means it is open?

Comment: @David: $A$ is not *a priori* a subset of $Y,$ so need not be open. In fact, $A$ need not even be a *set*! However, $\{A\}$ is an open subset of $Y.$ Likewise, $B$ need not be a subset of $Y$, nor even a set. However, $\{B\}$ is a closed (and *non-open*) subset of $Y.$

Comment: As I discussed above, given an arbitrary function $f:X\to Y,$ we have that $f$ is continuous *if and only if* $f^{-1}\bigl[\{A\}\bigr]$ is open. Verifying openness of the preimages of $\{A\}$ under the functions I  defined above is the same as verifying those functions' continuity.